# how add currency separator or currency denominations when user entering value in UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, uitextfield

A little confusion is here.i just want to add currency separator when user enter value and adjust separators position when user edit that value.i tried it in this but it only deals with recently entered character

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)text
```

if any one knows any better delegate method then please....

Answer (score 0):

Check below code, might help and change as per your requirement:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)text{

   NSDecimalNumber *amount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString: textField.text];

   NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

   [currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
   NSString *formattedCurrency = [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:amount];

   if ([formattedCurrency isEqualToString:@"NaN"]) {

       formattedCurrency=@"";
   }
   textField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",formattedCurrency];

   return YES;

}
```

Comment: Ok let me simplify it, in my case just want to add "." after every three digit from right side

Comment: Above code will format amount according locale automatically.

Comment: debug and check what's going on@jaymala